# Minecraft dedicated server on Ubuntu on an Android phone no such a file or directory

Tags: server, android, minecraft

I have tried to run Minecraft dedicated server on Ubuntu on an Android phone I get an error no such file or directory I have run it with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../bedrock_server` and `./bedrock_server.` Both with the same outcome.

What can I do to fix that? I am using **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** installed with Termux terminal emulator and Andronix.

Comment: What is Ubuntu 20.2?

Comment: It should be ubuntu 20.04 LTS, sorry for that

Comment: So you're running Ubuntu 20.04 on an Android phone?

Comment: Yes. there is a lot of guides how to do that, but maybe there is something missing.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to clarify how you run Ubuntu on your Android phone. Is it using a 3rd-party app? Terminal emulator? Flashing the OS from the bootloader?

Comment: I have used Androinix and Termux terminal emulator.